# Do I need a transit visa for South Korea? (under 24 hours)

Tags: france, japan, transit-visas, south-korea, bangladeshi-citizens

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen who has been living in Japan for the past year on a student visa. As such, I have a valid residence card for Japan. I’m planning to travel to France, with a transit through Seoul Incheon for approximately 12 hours.

I was wondering if I need a South Korean transit visa. Might be irrelevant information, but I have visited Seoul once in the past year.

Comment: `I have been to Seoul once in the past 1 year` -- with a visa?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/101253/47344 part 2 could apply, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#Transit) says:

> In general, travelers in transit do not require a visa to transit through South Korea for less than 24 hours (for Incheon Airport) or when departing on the same calendar day (for all other airports) as long as they stay within the transit area.
>
> Citizens of the following countries, however, must hold a Korean visa for transit:
>         Egypt, Sudan,  Syria,  Yemen

Answer (score 1):

TIMATIC (the database airlines use to check visa requirements) shows that a visa will not be required. [You can enter your details here](https://www.united.com/web/en-us/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) to if you'd like to check yourself.